# input text box “on the fly” filtering list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input, filtering

I need to filter a list (ul) with more than one input text box.
I´ve seen examples using only one input (see the code below):
http://jsfiddle.net/EFTZR/441/

```js
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){
    
    var that = this, $allListElements = $('ul > li');

    var $matchingListElements = $allListElements.filter(function(i, li){
        var listItemText = $(li).text().toUpperCase(), searchText = that.value.toUpperCase();
        return ~listItemText.indexOf(searchText);
    });
    
    $allListElements.hide();
    $matchingListElements.show();
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />

<ul id="category1">
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>item27</li>
    <li>item28</li>
</ul>
```

which works nice, but i´m not able to do it with two or more inputs working together "on the fly".
Any idea or advice?

Comment: what do you mean by *not able to do it with two or more inputs working together*

Comment: Hi Sandeep joshi, thanks for your response. What i mean is to be able to filter based on two conditions, in this case, the value of two or more input boxes. Fortunately i found a very good example from Daniel Parkes based on attributes which is so easy to modify. Maybe this can be useful for people looking for the same functionality, especially for list filtering. This is the link [https://jsfiddle.net/JokerDan/tqv0ybbz/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/JokerDan/tqv0ybbz/2/)